# What's the problem with these alphabetic collisions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading Halmos' *Naive Set Theory.*

> According to the usual and natural convention "for some $y\,(x\,
> \epsilon \, A)$" just means "$x\, \epsilon \, A"$. It's equally
>   harmless if the letter used has already been used with "for some-" or
>   "for all-." **Recall that "for some $x \, (x\, \epsilon \, A)$ means the
>   same as "for some $y\, (y\, \epsilon \, A) $**; it follows that a
>   judicious change of notation will always avert alphabetic collisions.

It seems they change the letter to avoid these alphabetic collisions, but what's the problem with it? For me, it's clearer when it's stated without the letter chaging, just as in the bold text. Where are these alphabetic collisions going to be harmful? In the past, I felt confused when I saw *"for some $y\,(x\, \epsilon \, A)$"*, I thought it was a statament about two objects.

[I've also asked something similar before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182806/why-does-this-text-insist-on-changing-the-variable-name-here)

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Can you give more context?

Comment: The $>$ is a typo.

Comment: do you mean to use the symbol $\in$?

Comment: @Holdsworth88: The $\in$ symbol is known as $\epsilon$-relation. In fact the original notation used $\epsilon$ and you can find old papers which used it that way. Halmos' book is quite old nowadays.

Comment: I believe I have corrected two typos in the quoted text.

Comment: @Ted I don't know why this thing of changing the letters exist. Is this helping?

Comment: I think that when Halmos writes "alphabetic collisions" he is referring to "for some $y(x\in A)$", and he suggests avoiding these by writing "for some $x(x\in A)$" instead. That is, Halmos wants to do what *you* want to do, and wants to avoid the sort of statement you find confusing. He is agreeing with you.

Comment: Part of the problem is that Halmos is discussing logic at a somewhat informal level. One needs to pay attention to these issues when treating first order logic in a more formal setting, after all, typically we present axiom schemas where we start with a formula $\varphi(y)$ and end with $\varphi(x)$. Informally, it is clear what this means. Formally, we need to talk about free and bound appearances of a variable in a formula, and things are simpler to define if $x$ is just not present in $\varphi$ to begin with.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So do people write like "For some $x$ $($$y$ $\in$ $A$$)$"?

Comment: People write all kinds of things. I'm marking an advanced undergraduate exam and seeing $3-2=-1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's strange because I've seen this on books written by professional mathematicians.

Comment: Cite?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Look in the link I provided in the end of the question, there's an example of letter switching for no known reason.

Comment: I don't see any similarity between C & R using $n$ in one formula and later using $r$ instead, and someone writing "For some $x$ ($y\in A$)."

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why not?

Comment: Why not? Either because I'm too stupid to see the similarity, or because there isn't any. What similarity do you see between a formula that has no existential quantifier and no set inclusion statement, and a formula that has both?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not seeing similarity between the formulas, I'm seeing similarity only in the change of letters.

Comment: Sorry, Gustavo, you've lost me. You ask why people write "For some $x$ ($y\in A$)", you claim to have seen this written by mathematicians, but the only example you produce is an example of something else entirely. I don't know what you want, but I'm beginning to think it has nothing to do with "For some $x$ ($y\in A$)". Maybe you should think about what you really want, and edit the body of your question to reflect it, or post a new question entirely (but with a link back to this one).

Comment: @GerryMyerson My entire point is similar to the post I linked, why do people change the letters in these cases.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I'm pretty sure Halmos is *not* telling the reader to write “for some $x$, $x\in A$” instead of “for some $y$, $y\in A$,” since those are completely different sentences.

Comment: @Steve, I didn't write that Halmos was saying that, so why address such a comment to me?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry: I mistyped one $x$ as a $y$. You wrote (I quote you) that Halmos suggests writing **"'for some $x(x\in A)$' instead [of] 'for some $y(x\in A)$'"**." Which I'm sure he was not saying, since that rewriting would change the mathematical meaning. (What I accidentally said you said was actually what I think Halmos was saying. What you did say he couldn't have been saying.)

Answer (score 2):

**Paragraph added after reading the OP’s previous question about renaming:**

It’s really helpful for (aspiring) mathematicians to understand a couple of things that are more often taught in computer science than mathematics: a) the difference between *bound* and *free* variables in mathematical expressions, and b) the fact that the logical statements mathematicians write (especially if-then statements) often have hidden quantifiers. The following two statements mean the same thing:

*If $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even.*

*If $r^2$ is even, then $r$ is even.*

This is because the variable in each is *bound* by a hidden/unwritten *for all* quantifier. On the other hand, the statements *$n$ is even* and *$r$ is even* do **not** mean the same thing, because in those, the variables are *free* — there is no *for all* or *there exists* quantifier (hidden or not). They are statements about a specific variable, $n$ or $r$. When combining statements that use the same letter, it’s often convenient to rename bound variables (where the particular letter is essentially meaningless) to avoid confusion.

**My original answer:**

Halmos is not saying that you should change letters when it changes the meaning.

The context for this is [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&lpg=PA6&ots=EfjK_yndEW&dq=%22alphabetic%20collisions%22%20halmos&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22alphabetic%20collisions%22%20halmos&f=false), where Halmos describes what a *sentence* is so that he can discuss the axiom of specification. He gives his description with a set of grammatical productions. Formalizing it with [Backus-Narr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), it goes like this:

```
<letter> ::= a|b|c|...|A|B|C|... (Halmos doesn't list the <letter>s.)

<sentence> ::=
    (<letter> ∈ <letter>)
  | (<letter> = <letter>)
  | (<sentence> and <sentence>)
  | (<sentence> or <sentence>)
  | (not <sentence>)
  | (if <sentence> then sentence)
  | (<sentence> if and only if <sentence>)
  | (for some <letter>, <sentence>)
  | (for all <letter>, <sentence>)
```

Halmos assumes the reader pretty much knows what the possible sentences mean, but he takes a moment to point out (in different words than mine, and rather incompletely for modern readers, I think) that changing letters might be useful to clarify things. Consider these two sentences:

```
for some x, (x ∈ B)
(x ∈ A)
```

The first one doesn’t “depend on `x`,” because `x` is *bound* by the quantifier. The second one does “depend on `x`”; `x` is *free*. No problem so far, but it becomes confusing if you combine the two into this compound sentence:

```
((for some x, (x ∈ B)) and (x ∈ A))
```

The meaning is unambiguous (`x` is in `A`, and `B` is not empty), but why not write it this way, which is clearer?

```
((x ∈ A) and (for some y, (y ∈ B)))
```

(Note that you can’t change the first `x` to `y` instead, because then the result depends on `y`, not `x`.) For another context where this renaming of bound variables is useful read about [$\alpha$-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion) in the lambda calculus.

Answer (score 1):

His claim in the first sentence is just that
$$
\exists{y}:\phi(x)
$$
means the same as
$$
\phi(x),
$$
because the existentially quantified variable ($y$) doesn't appear in the formula being quantified.  (The first form is confusing, though, because it makes you wonder if it's a typo and should read $\exists{x}:\phi(x)$ instead.)  This part of the paragraph is *not* related to the next part, except in that he's explaining different ways to form mathematical statements.  His claim in the next sentence is that it's fine to form a sentence like
$$
\exists{x}:\left(\forall{x}:\phi(x)\right).
$$
I don't know that I agree with that claim… surely that sentence is ambiguous at best.  But no one needs to use the ambiguous form: as he concludes by pointing out, you can always choose the names of your quantified variables to avoid any such collision of notation.

Comment: That is not his claim. He's just saying something very simple: that since we have choice on what symbol to use, we should use that choice and avoid collisions.

Comment: How do you interpret this?  "It's equally harmless if the letter used has already been used with 'for some-' or 'for all-'."

Comment: See the context from [the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false) — he's saying two separate things about the grammar he defined: One, "if the letter used does not occur in the sentence, no harm is done" (because $\exists{y}:\phi(x)$ means same as $\phi(x)$, you can just remove what's redundant). Two, "it is equally harmless if the letter used has already been used" (because $\exists{x}:\phi(x)$ and $\exists{y}:\phi(y)$ mean the same thing, we can always use a different letter).